# How can I run cplex program from c# code?

Tags: c#, cplex

I have a cplex code that works in cplex ide. I want to run that program inside c# code.

I added cplex libraries, but visual studio cannot understand it.

```cs
using ILOG.CPLEX;
using ILOG.Concert;
```

but these are red underlined. How can I connect cplex library to c# code? I want to run cplex code like a function, I mean:

```cs
int cost = run_cplex_output();
```

Comment: from the sounds of it, you haven't added cplex as a reference to your project

Comment: how can i add it? on internet all solutions are for c++, c++ settings and c# settings are different in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

- 1) Use the Concert C# API
- 2) Use the C# OPL API to call OPL from C#

In the CPLEX product you have examples for [option 1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Examples/topics/exampleCsharpDotNet.html) at

CPLEX_Studio129\cplex\examples\src\cs

and [option 2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplexamples/topics/opl_examples_interfaces_where.html) at

CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\dotnet\x64_windows_vs2017\CSharp

I suggest option 2 and see [Mulprod.cs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.ide.help/examples/html/opl_interfaces/dotnet/x86_windows_vs2010/CSharp/Mulprod/Mulprod.cs.html)

Comment: 20: using ILOG.Concert;
21: using ILOG.CPLEX;
22: using ILOG.OPL; these are red underlined on my project. my code cannot understand cplex libraries.